# Spring, can't change SessionAuthenticationStrategy in Java config

Tags: spring, spring-security

I want to disable session-fixation-protection on Spring-Boot (using version 1.2.4). We are configuring the httpSecurity in Java:

SecurityConfig.Scala

```
  override def configure(http: HttpSecurity): Unit = {
    println("loading config")
    http.
      csrf().disable().
      authorizeRequests().
      antMatchers("/api/member/**").permitAll().
      antMatchers("/api/feedback/submit").permitAll().
      antMatchers("/test/**").permitAll().
      antMatchers("/session").access("hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')").
        anyRequest().anonymous().and().
      securityContext().securityContextRepository(memcachedSecurityContextRepository).and().
      formLogin().
        loginPage("/login").failureUrl("/denied").defaultSuccessUrl("/session").and().
      logout().invalidateHttpSession(true).logoutSuccessUrl("/login").and().
      sessionManagement().invalidSessionUrl("/login").maximumSessions(1).expiredUrl("/login").and().
      sessionFixation().none()
  }
}
```

Here is some Debug from Spring while executing the above code:

> loading config
>
> Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for Ant
>   [pattern='/api/member/**']
>
> Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for Ant
>   [pattern='/api/feedback/submit']
>
> Adding web access control expression 'permitAll', for Ant
>   [pattern='/test/**']
>
> Adding web access control expression 'hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN')', for Ant
>   [pattern='/session']
>
> Adding web access control expression 'anonymous', for
>   org.springframework.security.web.util.matcher.AnyRequestMatcher@1
>   Validated configuration attributes
>
> Validated configuration attributes

Here the debug output while authentication:

> COOKIEVAL:Some(mh3dg7l715nhvtfdfpng11ooa7)
>
> /api/member/account at position 3 of 12 in additional filter chain;
>   firing Filter: 'HeaderWriterFilter'
>
> Not injecting HSTS header since it did not match the requestMatcher
>   org.springframework.security.web.header.writers.HstsHeaderWriter$SecureRequestMatcher@4e2ca7d9
>
> /api/member/account at position 4 of 12 in additional filter chain;
>   firing Filter: 'LogoutFilter'
>
> Checking match of request : '/api/member/account'; against '/logout'
>
> /api/member/account at position 5 of 12 in additional filter chain;
>   firing Filter: 'UsernamePasswordAuthenticationFilter'
>
> Checking match of request : '/api/member/account'; against '/login'
>
> /api/member/account at position 6 of 12 in additional filter chain;
>   firing Filter: 'ConcurrentSessionFilter'
>
> /api/member/account at position 7 of 12 in additional filter chain;
>   firing Filter: 'RequestCacheAwareFilter'
>
> /api/member/account at position 8 of 12 in additional filter chain;
>   firing Filter: 'SecurityContextHolderAwareRequestFilter'
>
> /api/member/account at position 9 of 12 in additional filter chain;
>   firing Filter: 'AnonymousAuthenticationFilter'
>
> SecurityContextHolder not populated with anonymous token, as it
>   already contained:
>   'org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@4525caad:
>   Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@586034f:
>   Username: admin; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true;
>   AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true;
>   AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN; Credentials:
>   [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities:
>   ROLE_ADMIN'
>
> /api/member/account at position 10 of 12 in additional filter chain;
>   firing Filter: 'SessionManagementFilter'
>
> /api/member/account at position 11 of 12 in additional filter chain;
>   firing Filter: 'ExceptionTranslationFilter'
>
> /api/member/account at position 12 of 12 in additional filter chain;
>   firing Filter: 'FilterSecurityInterceptor'
>
> Checking match of request : '/api/member/account'; against
>   '/api/member/**'
>
> Secure object: FilterInvocation: URL: /api/member/account; Attributes:
>   [permitAll]
>
> Previously Authenticated:
>   org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken@4525caad:
>   Principal: org.springframework.security.core.userdetails.User@586034f:
>   Username: admin; Password: [PROTECTED]; Enabled: true;
>   AccountNonExpired: true; credentialsNonExpired: true;
>   AccountNonLocked: true; Granted Authorities: ROLE_ADMIN; Credentials:
>   [PROTECTED]; Authenticated: true; Details: null; Granted Authorities:
>   ROLE_ADMIN
>
> Voter:
>   org.springframework.security.web.access.expression.WebExpressionVoter@28549e18,
>   returned: 1
>
> Authorization successful
>
> RunAsManager did not change Authentication object
>
> /api/member/account reached end of additional filter chain; proceeding
>   with original chain

What do i have to do to prevent that the cookie value is changed after authentication ? I thought calling sessionFixation().none() would turn of session-fixation-protection.

Answer (score 1):

In my case, this helped:

```
http
  .sessionManagement()
    .sessionAuthenticationStrategy(new NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy()).and()
  ....
```

NullAuthenticatedSessionStrategy will do nothing on authentication.

> Doing this is unsafe!
>   this only for testing purposes!

Comment: I would argue that in some cases this is warranted (and safe) - like for example, I have an application that is stateless, and uses JWT tokens with a custom filter that checks the JWT tokens and sets Authentication in the Context. But standard AuthenticationStrategy ends up triggering `onAuthentication` every time (since EVERY request sets an `Authentication` inside of filter). Therefore if I want to keep CSRF protection, I need to trigger onAuthentication manually after the initial "login", so I disable it here.